# NY Times For Android Tablets User-Interface Design

Tags: android, user-interface

I came across [NY Times for android tablet](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nytimes.android.tablet).

It introduce UI design for selecting which sections you want to read in a way similar to how you open notifications (press menu bar and swipe down to open it).

I wonder, what is it called and how do we mimic this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)